# Approximation of log(n!)

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, factorial

I just finished calculus 1 (derivative and integral) then I take another course on calculus 2. In the video the professor talks about the the series $$\frac{n!}{(\frac{n}{e})^n}$$

He shows the approximation of the numerator ($n!$) and the denominator ($(\frac{n}{e})^n$) he approximates $\log(n!)$ using $$\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k) \approx \int_1^n\log(x) \text{d}x$$

I'm very curious because I think the $\log(n!)$ is a step function. I tried it with graphing calculator [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) but it shows continuous function. Is the calculator wrong? Because $n!$ has whole number as a domain so $\log(n!)$ should also be a step function?

My second question is can we apply integral to a step function? What is the result different from continuous function, and how can we distinguish. For example when we have $f(x) = x^2$ and we want to do integral with the step domain (whole number) or all the domain?

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnPBmJ70fzg) is the video (you can go and view it at 2:30)

I'm a beginner in this field please explain a step by step and beginner friendly to me.

Comment: Who said $n!$ is a only defined on postive integers? Wouldn't that be a bit boring? I recommend reading about the Gamma function, as $n!$, Calc 1 should be sufficient understanding its definition.

Comment: The function $\log (n!):\Bbb N\to \Bbb R$ is continuous. Maybe you are thinking about the function $\log \lfloor x\rfloor !:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ what is a step (discontinuous) function.

Comment: In that approximation, both on the LHS and on the RHS, $n$ is intended to be a positive integer.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan, so if the n on both side is intended to be positive integer. Can we take the integral of step function??? can you also answer the part of my question about integration

Comment: @user3270418: I don't understand the question. There is no step function underneath the integral. The function being integrated is $\log x$.

Comment: sorry for my misconception. alright, now the question is, is it ok to approximate the summation above (which is a step function) with integral of continuous function???? it is like we have a function that looks like a 2x2 square and we compute a summation of step which is (0,2) (1,2) (2,2) which is 2+2+2 = 6 but if we use integration we get 2X2 = 4 ???

Comment: If you precede 'log' with a backslash, it will become the LaTeX symbol for logarithm and look like a function name: `\log` → $\log$ instead of multiplication of 'ell', 'ou' and 'gee': `log` → $log$.

Comment: The main contribution to the sum ( asymptotic ) comes from 'large' $n$. However, for 'large' $x$, $\ln\left(x\right)$ varies slowly $\left(~\ln'\left(x\right) = 1/x \ll 1~\right)$ such that the sum is approximated by the integral. There are, of course, large errors for small $n$ values but for 'large' $n$ they are masked by the asymptotic contribution. The teacher just did a shortcut for the whole explanation as it usually happens in a lecture ( I guess so !!! ).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, $\log(n!)$ is not a step function, because it's not a function defined on (an interval of) the reals; it is defined on a discrete set. A step function, roughly speaking, is a function with a discrete *range*. This one is a function with a discrete *domain*.

Secondly, both $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\log k\;$ and $\displaystyle\int_1^n\log x\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x\;$ are functions of $n$. Your professor is asserting that these two expressions are *equivalent at* $\infty$ (denoted $\sim_\infty$) in a very precise sense, not that their values are approximately the same (denoted $\;\approx$), which is not a mathematically defined notion.

The precise definition of equivalence here is that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\log k}{\displaystyle\int_1^n\log x\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}=1.$$

Thus one might say, very very roughly, that $\;\approx\;$ means ‘absolutely almost equal’, while $\;\sim\;$  means ‘comparatively almost equal’.

Comment: how can both be equivalent??? assume that we have a long horizontal rectangle box 10x1000 (height x width) if we sum the height at width 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...,1000 and compare it with the area (which is the integration of this box) do we get the number that equivalent? and is it apply to any case???

Comment: The numerical value of the height is also the numerical value of the area of a rectangle with width equal to  $1$. Don't forget the variable $k$ varies  by steps of $1$. So both the sum and the integral can be interpreted as an area.

Comment: Do I have to study numerical method? or I just need to brush up my definition of integral a little bit more? I do not understand the word numerical value. is it just a value?

Comment: It was just to emphasize it's a number. No, you don't have to study numerical methods at this stage: it's purely conceptual. For the integral, all you have to know is about Riemann sums.

Comment: thank you very much for your great answer. one last question. the log(n!) function is not a step function but also not continuous? right? and the graphing calculator shows the wrong result? https://www.desmos.com/calculator for the log(n!)? because the right graph will be dots, ex: (1,y) (2,y) (3,y) (4,y)... (n,y)?

Comment: but someone also said that it's a gamma function which is a non-step function? but is it because in the video the professor are talking about series which is limited to the n = whole number in this specific case? so the log(n!) in this case has discrete domain but other case is not.

Comment: I guess your graph calculator displays only functions defined on intervals. I know some calculators can display sequences, which  would be better fitted. For the log(n!) function, you can say it's continuous, but as **N** has the discrete topology, *any* function defined on **N** will be continuous – in other  words  the notion of continuity is irrelevant here.

Comment: The gamma function is a way to extend the *factorial* to positive numbers (and more generally to complex numbers except non-positive integers). It is defined as the parametric integral $$\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}\mathrm e^{-t}\,\mathrm d\mkern 1mu t.$$ One proves that $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$.

Comment: @Bernard It's great fun and a good exercise proving that $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) it is very easy to see that $$S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\left(n\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}1\cdot\log\left(n\right)
 $$ $$=n\log\left(n\right)-\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }{t}dt
 $$ where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor 
 $ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). Since $t-1\leq\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor \leq t
 $ we have $$n\log\left(n\right)-n-1\leq S_{n}\leq n\log\left(n\right)-n+1+\log\left(n\right).
 $$ hence $$\int_{1}^{n}\log\left(t\right)dt\leq S_{n}\leq\int_{1}^{n}\log\left(t\right)dt+\log\left(n\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

First question : It exists a function called [the Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) that is a "non-step" factorial. This means it is a smooth curve that somehow extends the notion of factorial to any real (complex) numbers. In particular, for any positive integer, the value of the gamma function and the classic factorial function are the same (shifted by $1$). I give you some values :
$$
\Gamma(1) = 0! = 1 \\
\Gamma(2) = 1! = 1 \\
\Gamma(3) = 2! = 2 \\
\Gamma(4) = 3! = 6 \\
\Gamma(3/2) = \frac{1}{2}! = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
$$
Many math softwares can evaluate non-integer factorial by using this gamma function !

Second question : Yes ! You simply cut the steps into a sum of integral. Think of the function floor $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$. And let's say you want to compute its integral :
$$
\int_0^3 f(x) dx = \int_0^1 f(x) dx + \int_1^2 f(x) dx + \int_2^3 f(x) dx \\ = \int_0^1 0\ dx + \int_1^2 1\ dx + \int_2^3 2\ dx = \\
0 + 1 + 2 = 3
$$
On the other hand, if you consider simply the non-step function $g(x) = x$ then $\int_0^3 g(x) dx = 9/2$ which is close but not exactly the same as with $f(x)$. Simply draw the two functions and $\textit{see}$ the area under their curve !

Comment: do you think the function use for approximation in the video is a step function or non-step function?

Comment: Clearly $f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n log(k !)$ is a step function since $n$ can only takes integer value, otherwise the symbol of the sum would be meaningless. How would you define $\sum_{k=1}^{3.742} ...$ ?

Comment: how can we approximate the summation above with integral??? assume that we have a long horizontal rectangle box 10x1000 (height x width) if we sum the height at width 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...,1000 and compare it with the area (which is the integration of this box) do we get the number that equivalent? and is it apply to any case???

Comment: @user3270418 In the case of a perfect rectangular box, the sum and the integral will be exactly the same ! In your case $\sum_{k=1}^{1000} 10 = \int_0^{1000} 10\ dx$ (Note their is usually a shift of $1$ between the bounds for the sum and the integral). The summation actually computes an approximation of the integral with rectangle of size $1 \times f(x)$. If $f(x)$ is constant then you get your example with a fixes rectangle $10 \times 1000$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not terribly difficult to compare:
$$ \color{blue}{C_n} = \int_{1}^{n}\log(x)\,dx =\color{blue}{n\log(n)-n+1},\qquad \color{purple}{D_n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(k).$$
Assuming $n\geq 2$, summation by parts leads to:
$$ \color{purple}{D_n} = n \log n -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k \log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)=\color{blue}{n\log(n)-n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-k\log\frac{k+1}{k}\right) $$
but:
$$ 0\leq 1-k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\leq \frac{1}{2k} $$
hence:

> $$\color{blue}{C_n} \leq \color{purple}{D_n} \leq \color{blue}{C_n}+\frac{\log n}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard trick here. In what follows, $a,b,k,n$ all refer to integer variables, $x$ to a real variable, and $\lfloor \  \rfloor$ refers to the floor function: $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $x$.

---

First, we can relate the sum to the integral of a step function by using the fact
$$ f(n) = \int_{n}^{n+1} f(\lfloor x \rfloor) \, \mathrm{d} x =  \int_{n-1}^{n} f(\lfloor x+ 1 \rfloor) \, \mathrm{d} x $$
and consequently
$$ \sum_{k=a}^b f(k) = \int_a^{b+1} f(\lfloor x \rfloor) \, \mathrm{d} x =  \int_{a-1}^{b} f(\lfloor x+ 1 \rfloor) \, \mathrm{d} x  $$
This is probably what made you think of step functions; while $\log(k)$ is itself not a step function, $\log \lfloor x \rfloor$ is. (the other possibility is that you were thinking of something like $\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \log k$)

---

Second, for any nondecreasing function $f(x)$, we have inequalities

$$ f(n-1) \leq f(\lfloor n \rfloor) \leq f(n) \leq f(\lfloor n+1 \rfloor) $$

which carries over to the integrals:

$$ \int_{a-1}^{b-1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x \leq \int_a^b f(\lfloor x \rfloor) \, \mathrm{d} x 
\leq  \int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x 
\leq  \int_{a+1}^{b+1} f(\lfloor x \rfloor) \, \mathrm{d} x $$

and consequently,

$$ \int_{a-1}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x
\leq \sum_{k=a}^b f(k) 
\leq  \int_a^{b+1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x $$

---

Applying this to the problem at hand, we get

$$ \int_{1}^{n} \log x \, \mathrm{d} x
\leq \sum_{k=2}^n \log k
\leq  \int_2^{n+1} \log x \, \mathrm{d} x $$

which we can then use to make rigorous estimates about the size of the sum.

(I split off the $k=1$ term to avoid problems with the integrals; but it's zero anyways so it doesn't affect the total. You could get a more accurate estimate by splitting off more terms, computing them exactly, then adding the result back into the inequality)